# SQL Server XML field - using TSQL variable as XML node sequence indicator

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, variables, xmltype

Why does this work?

```
SELECT
  XDocument
    .value('(/Book/Chapter[@verse="allo"])[2]',
      nvarchar(max)')
FROM XBiblos
WHERE Version = 666
```

---

But WHY does this not work? Where the only diff is that `[2]` is replaced by `[sql:variable("@i")]`

Which results in error msg 
`'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'`

```
DECLARE @i int;
SET @i = 2;

SELECT
  XDocument
    .value('(/Book/Chapter[@verse="allo"])[sql:variable("@i")]',
      nvarchar(max)')
FROM XBiblos
WHERE Version = 666
```

---

Doc structure example ...

```
<XDocument name="DraXQueLah">
  <Book name="Worldymort">
    <Chapter verse="Forgot">Forgot so loved the world</Chapter >
    <Chapter verse="Icecream">That we were eternally creamed</Chapter >
    <Chapter verse="blah">blah blah</Chapter >    
    <Chapter verse="blah">blah blah</Chapter >    
    <Chapter verse="blah">blah blah</Chapter >    
    <Chapter verse="blah blah">blah blah blah</Chapter >    
  </Book>
</XDocument>
```

Comment: jd, that is how sql:variable() function is used. Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `[1]` to enforce a singleton. The engine knows, that `[2]` (which is the position), will - for sure! - have only one (or none) result. But the engine is not able to predict, that your expression will result in one single result:

```
DECLARE @i int;
SET @i = 2;

SELECT
  XDocument
    .value('(/Book/Chapter[@verse="allo"])[sql:variable("@i")][1]', --<--Here
      nvarchar(max)')
FROM XBiblos
WHERE Version = 666
```